# Issue With PHP Contact Form

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have made a PHP script and a contact form in html. However, when I fill the form, it say's the email was sent but when I get the email it looks like this:

Name: 
Email:
Skype:
Message:

It says them but not what I actually typed in the contact form next to them.

My HTML and PHP is on this link: https://hastebin.com/osilogatar.xml

Comment: Try echoing the values of the `$_REQUEST` variable in your `mail.php` to make sure they have content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$body = " Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Skype: $skype \n Message: $message \n\n IP Address: $ip";
```

Use this, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly. Appreciate it. Small mistakes break everything. Haha.

Comment: Every time someone fills out my contact form, it sends a strange email.

https://hastebin.com/ipiditudon.http


Also, how do I make it so it opens a bootstrap modal when the email successfully sends.

Answer (score 0):

Try this "Name: {$name } ... and so on